# Angular2/Firebase - Array1 be equal to array2 without binding them together

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry I'm finding it difficult to word the issue I'm having correctly..

I have an array called `feedCounter` and an array called `postFeed`. I want to display the length of `feedCounter` and when a user clicks on it `postFeed` becomes equal to `feedCounter`, but when `feedCounter` gets a new element `postFeed` should not update with it...

What I'm doing is setting `feedCounter` to a `snapshot` in firebase:

```
this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    this.feedCounter.push(snapshot.val());
});
```

and then in my `html` I do this:

```
<div (click)="postFeed = feedCounter;">{{feedCounter?.length}}</div>
<post *ngFor="let post of postFeed.reverse()"></post>
```

The problem is, `postFeed` seems to be getting binded to `feedCounter` after the first time I click on the `div` `postFeed` automatically gets updated, which I do not want..

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is you assign `postFeed = feedCounter;` so both variable will reference to the same array and add new element to feedCounter just same as add new element to postFeed. To separate those you should clone it before assign like this: `postFeed = feedCounter.slice(0);`

Comment: That's a very elegant way to clone the array, much simpler than the one I thought; just a note, that will create a shallow clone, not a deep one, AFAIK :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this in your click handler:

```
postFeed = feedCounter
```

You need to create a copy of feedcounter; otherwise, you are making them both point to the same object (the same array). So,

```
postFeed = copy(feedCounter)
```

Now the copy function you must implement, there are several ways to do it, you can google it (how to copy array javascript), use a lib like lodash, or implement it yourself.

One option is to JSON parse and unparse:

```
copy = (arr) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

You need to decide if you want shallow or deep, if you need to deal with circular dependencies, etc.

Comment: This was a good answer, but I chose to go with the other answer as it seems simpler.. thank you